# Problem with duplicate CKEditor5 when passing data into Modal

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal, ckeditor5

I use AJAX requests to get data from the database. When I pass each data into the input form, it's okay, but when I transfer the data to CKEditor5, I get an error: every time I close and reopen the modal, the modal will appear. The data passed into CKEditor is not changed but creates a new CKEditor. This is my code for Modal and AJAX request

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailModal"
        aria-hidden="true" id="detailPlaceModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title h4" id="detailModal">Detail Place</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-ghost-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="tio-clear tio-lg"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="detailContent">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="describe_place">Mô tả</label>
                                <textarea id="editCKeditor" class="form-control" name="describe_view_place"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button data-modal-hide="defaultModal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">I
                                    accept</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
function getDetailPlace(event, element) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(element).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response) {
                    var detailData = response.vlplace[0];  
                    $('#describe_view_place').val(detailData.describe_place);
                    ClassicEditor
                        .create(document.querySelector('#editCKeditor'))
                        .then(editor => {
                            var describeValue = detailData.describe_place;
                            editor.setData(describeValue);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error(error);
                        });
                    $('#detailPlaceModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            });
}
```

I researched and fix it but couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

In AJAX

```
var myEditorSend;
function getDetailPlace(event, element) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(element).attr('href');
        editCKeditor();
        myEditorSend.setData('');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                var detailData = response.vlplace[0];  
                $('#describe_view_place').val(detailData.describe_place);
                var describeValue = detailData.describe_place;
                myEditorSend.setData(describeValue);
                $('#detailPlaceModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
      }
      var editCKeditor= () => {
       ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editCKeditor'))
        .then(editor => {
          myEditorSend = editor;
        // console.log(editor);
      })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error(error);
     });
    }
```

Comment: I tried to fix it but it didn't work, it still keeps repeating when creating a new ckeditor

Comment: I fixed it, I created ajax for another function and called it to get data into the classeditor's .then